# replacing an element in a list of lists -- haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform, haskell-pipes

I have this code :

```
type Matrice = [[String]]
matr =[[" - "," 0 "," - "],[" - "," - "," - "],[" - "," - "," - "]]       

changeValue :: Matrice ->Int->Int->Matrice
changeValue mat x y = [
    if ((mat !! x) !! y) /= " - "
        then mat
        else do (replaceNth y " P " xs)
    | xs <- (mat !! x)
    ]
```

replaceNth :: function replace a postion value ' - ' with a (' P ')

```
replaceNth :: Int -> String -> [String] -> [String]
replaceNth n newVal (x:xs)
     | n == 0 = newVal:xs
     | otherwise = x:replaceNth (n-1) newVal xs
```

I want to change each case have ' - ' to ' P ' in a Matrix

But It's not working , I have always this Error :

```
couldn't match type [char] with char
```

Comment: Please post the complete source code, we so can see what you're trying to run, and the complete error message, so we can see where the error is being reported.

Comment: @SamiLi Please edit your question with your code, the comments section is not the place to put code relevant to your question.

Comment: I think it's better now :)

Comment: @SamiLi The problem is that you're trying to return a list of `Matrice` with your comprehension, but you've stated in the function signature that you're returning a single `Matrice`.  Additionally, the line `do (replicateNth y " P " xs)` does not need the `do`, but in this case I don't think it's affecting anything.  I believe you'll have a type error there though.  Maybe you should have written something like `if ((mat !! x) !! Y) /= " - " then mat else [replaceNth y " P " xs | xs <- mat !! xs]`

Comment: That comprehension is just equivalent to `map (replaceNth y " P ") (mat !! xs)`, by the way, and I for one prefer that syntax, but either styles are acceptable.

Comment: One final note, your `replaceNth` is going to cause you problems because you aren't handling when you pass it an empty list, you should have a `replaceNth n newVal [] = ...` clause in your definition.

Comment: What is the intent of `changeValue`? - does it change the value only at one location or perform the change at all locations? If at all locations - why do you pass in `x` and `y`?

Comment: No it's just for one location (x,y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new to Haskell, so this may be sub-optimal in many ways, but I find it interesting to use the fact that Haskell is functional and polymorphic to replace your replaceNth function with a more general one that replaces an element in a list by the result of applying a function to said element:

```
changeNth :: Int->(a->a)->[a]->[a]
changeNth n change (x:xs)
     | n == 0 = (change x):xs
     | otherwise = x:changeNth (n-1) change xs
```

Now you can use this twice to accomplish what you want:

```
changeValue :: Matrice ->Int->Int->Matrice
changeValue mat x y = changeNth x (changeNth y
  (\v -> if v==" - " then " P " else v)) mat
```

My tests:

```
λ: let matr =[[" - "," 0 "," - "],[" - "," - "," - "],[" - "," - "," - "]]
λ: changeValue matr 1 1
[[" - "," 0 "," - "],[" - "," P "," - "],[" - "," - "," - "]]
λ: changeValue matr 0 1
[[" - "," 0 "," - "],[" - "," - "," - "],[" - "," - "," - "]]
```

Comment: This actually looks optimal: accessing a 2-dimensional list `[[a]]` requires following all the "cons"es (`:`) in both dimensions, much like following pointers in an imperative language. Of course, using an array (of arrays) would improve performance (as in imperative languages). Minor style suggestion: I would use pattern matching instead of guards in `changeNth 0 change (x:xs) = ... ; changeNth n change (x:xs) = ...`.

Comment: Oh, sure. I used "optimal" in the sense of "most readable" or "most idiomatic", so your suggestion is very welcome.